# How to check from bash if package exists in Debian

Tags: bash, apt, deb

I would like to write an installation bash script, where I would like to install MySQL server.

On Linux Mint I had followed code:

```
apt-get -y --force-yes install mysql-server-5.6
```

but I installed the new Debian 8 and there is no `mysql-server` - instead there is `mariadb`.

How can I find out if package exists?

I just know that there is `dpkg -s` which should tell whether a package is installed.

Comment: `--force-yes` deactivates all security, so you really could break your system to the point of no repair. Also: `--force-yes` overrides (deactivates) `-y`. where the latter could be the option of choice: A long form of `-y` is `--assume-yes`, and that's what it does; Saying yes until it could get really ugly, with  risking havoc among core elements, fundamentals, etc. `--force` overrides breaks security (learned it the hard way)

Comment: Addendum: You might be interested in the `--simulate`option for `apt-get`, to do a `--dry-run`, just in case

Comment: just to clarify: you want to find out if a package is in any of the repositories that are defined in `/etc/apt/sources.list`, right?

Comment: Note that there actually is a mysql-server package in Debian 8, alongside mariadb: https://packages.debian.org/jessie/mysql-server

Answer (score 17, accepted):

(the below is from Ubuntu, but the same technique obviously works on Debian as well)

```
$ apt-cache show screen
Package: screen
Priority: optional
Section: misc
Installed-Size: 950
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Original-Maintainer: Axel Beckert <abe@debian.org>
Architecture: amd64
Version: 4.1.0~20120320gitdb59704-9
Depends: libc6 (>= 2.15), libpam0g (>= 0.99.7.1), libtinfo5
Suggests: iselect (>= 1.4.0-1) | screenie | byobu
Filename: pool/main/s/screen/screen_4.1.0~20120320gitdb59704-9_amd64.deb
Size: 645730
...
```

If the package exists, information will be displayed. If not, you'll see something like:

```
$ apt-cache show foobar
N: Unable to locate package foobar
E: No packages found
```

Additionally, the exit code of `apt-cache` will be non-zero if no matching packages are found.

**Additional note:** If you're using `apt-cache show package` where package is a virtual one (one that doesn't exist, but is, for example, referenced by other packages), you'll get:

```
N: Can't select versions from package 'package' as it is purely virtual
N: No packages found
```

The `exit code` of this is zero (which is a bit misleading in my opinion.)

Comment: just to complete this answer: you can also search the defined repositories from the `sources.list` with this command: `apt-cache search *searchstring*`. That command will also search the description of packages and could help you find packages where you don't know the exact package name.

Comment: @wullxz, only the `apt-cache search ...` returns any kind of matches and the app. returns 0 even if nothing is found, which is not practical in a bash script.

Answer (score 5):

I would use `dpkg -l mysql-server &> /dev/null && echo "mysql-server is installed"`.

It will check if the `mysql-server` package is installed and if so, it prints this fact to the screen. A more sophisticated solution would be, in bash (untested):

```
function package_exists() {
    return dpkg -l "$1" &> /dev/null
}
```

So one can do in a script:

```
if ! package_exists mysql-server ; then
    echo ”Please install mysql-server!"
fi
```

Comment: I think he wants to know if the package exists at all and not if it is already installed on the local machine...

Answer (score 2):

In a one-liner:

`apt-cache pkgnames | grep -q "\<$your_package_name\>"`

exits with 0 if it's present, 1 if not.

**Bonus:** efficient check for multiple packages, listed in file "packages_we_want", one per line, sorted with `sort`:

`apt-cache --no-generate pkgnames | sort | comm -13 - packages_we_want` lists all packages that you want, but **do not** exist in the repositories.

`apt-cache --no-generate pkgnames | sort | comm -12 - packages_we_want` lists all packages that you want and exist in the repositories.

Answer (score 1):

My solution

```
function package_exists() {
    dpkg -s "$1" &> /dev/null
    return $?
}
```

```
if package_exists abra; then
    CLIENT=abra
elif package_exists cadabra; then
    CLIENT=cadabra
else
     echo 'Client not found!'
     exit 1
fi
```

Comment: (1) We prefer answers to have a bit more English text.  Your answer is approximately 8% text and 92% code; that's a bad ratio.  (2) If you had explained your answer, you would have said "Use `dpkg -s`."  But the OP already knows about `dpkg -s`, and seems to believe that it's not what they want.  Are you saying that the OP is wrong, and `dpkg -s` really does do what they want?  Please explain. … … … … … … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.